# Get current entry category

Tags: entries, categories, relations

I haven't used categories before so maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way.

I currently have a category group named products with the following structure:

```
Featured
Fruit
----Apple
----Banana
Veg
----Turnip
```

I know I can do the following to show just the subcategories of fruit:

```
for cat in craft.categories.group('productCategories').descendantOf("fruit ID")
```

But how do I get the "fruit ID" when I'm on the on the fruit page?

```
 craft.categories.relatedTo(entry)
```

returns all the categories in products but I want just the current category.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but technically a tomato is a fruit. ;)

Comment: the craft page on categories is a great way to learn some other elements of categories you might need for success. http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories

Comment: @BradBell for president

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are on the category template as defined in `admin/settings/categories/:id`.

You should have a model representation of the category assigned to `category` in the template, so you should be able to get the current category id by simply doing `{{ category.id }}` in the template.

Your code could look like:

`for cat in craft.categories.group('productCategories').descendantOf(category.id)`

Comment: Great, that's the issue, as I said I haven't used categories before so I thought I could use the entry variable but this makes sense as it's a category not an entry!

Answer (score 1):

When you are on a category page you can simply use the category variable just like you would use the entry variable...

```
{{ category.id }}
```